# How to make undefined bitshift "correct"

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

In C++, bit shifting an `n`-bit integer by `n` is undefined behaviour:

```
std::uint64_t v = 1;
v = v << 64; // Undefined behaviour
std::cout << v << std::endl;
```

The code above prints `1` on my machine. The "correct" result of such a bit shift should be 0 and a naive fix would be to use a branch:

```
std::uint64_t v = 1;
std::uint64_t offset = 64;
v = offset >= 64 ? 0 : v << offset;
std::cout << v << std::endl;
```

Is there any way to get the same result without using a branch?

Comment: Are you sure that's actually branching and causing you problems? A quick test showed the compiler I used optimizing this to use a cmov. That also seems like an extremely predictable branch in the first place.

Comment: Why do you care this has a "branch"? Did you test that this produces a branch in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

We want to fix things so that if `offset` is greater than or equal to 64, the result is zero.

Strategy:

1. Shift offset right by 6 bits, call this `temp`.
2. If `temp` is zero, we want to initialize a mask to all 1 bits, otherwise all 0 bits. We can accomplish this by setting `mask = !!temp - 1`.
3. Now just bitwise-and `v` and `offset` with `mask`.

Implementation:

```
uint64_t shift(uint64_t value, uint64_t offset) {
    uint64_t temp = offset >> 6;
    uint64_t mask = (!!temp) - 1;
    return (value & mask) << (offset & mask);
}
```

Instead of shifting `offset` you could also just bitwise-and it with `~0x3F`, would probably be faster.

```
uint64_t shift(uint64_t value, uint64_t offset) {
    uint64_t mask = (!!(offset & ~0x3F)) - 1;
    return (value & mask) << (offset & mask);
}
```

Comment: Did you profile this? This produces significantly more assembly than just a typical cmov.

Comment: It wasn't a performance question. The question was, "Is there any way to get the same result without using a branch?"

Comment: I mean...okay, but the usefulness is dubious. Surely OP is not asking for obfuscation purposes.

Comment: Looks like the same number of assembly instructions either way. https://godbolt.org/z/FmqTNG

Comment: Yeah, for clang 10 they match but for gcc they do not. Clang tends to optimize better IME. But, fair enough. Given writing the "obvious" code leads to the shorter (or equal) sequence in both, it's a good example of a) write the pattern your compiler is more likely to recognize, b) always peek at the result.

Comment: @GManNickG: What's maddening are the myriad cases where the best machine code that can be achieved from source code which is guaranteed to work is inferior to the best correct machine code that could be achieved using non-portable constructs which happen to work with today's compilers.